# Using label and break in if-else statement

Tags: java, break, labeled-statements

I have this code which generates random number from an array, at a particular condition (when x and y both are equal to zero). I want the control to jump to the label. But the control never jumps to the label in any condition. I wanted to know that whether I am doing it right or not?

```
int[] arr = {0, 1, 2};    
Random rn = new Random();
label: {
    //some code
    if (x != 0 && y !=0) {
        //some code
    } else {
        break label;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Luksprog: Thanks brother for editing, but the code is actually for android, for keeping it simple I removed that code and added comments in those places.

Comment: Don't you need `||` instead of `&&` in your `if`? I.e. `if (x != 0 || y != 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Try to</strike> Avoid using labels. What you could do there, is:

```java
while(true) {
    if(x == 0 && y == 0) {
        break;
    }
    // some stuff with x and y
}
```

Comment: OR: do { // some stuff } while (x!=0 || y!=0);   then can avoid the break too.

Comment: +1 but I'd remove word "try" from your answer: "*Avoid* using labels"

Comment: @sbk What if `x` and `y` already equal `0` before entering the loop?

Comment: @sp00m Its a do-while loop, so it will execute once before evaluating the condition.

Answer (score 13):

Without examining whether you should, **yes**, you can use labeled statements with `if` in Java. According to the [1.7 specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7)

> The Identifier is declared to be the label of the immediately contained Statement. [...] identifier statement labels are used with [break](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15) (§14.15) or [continue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16) (§14.16) statements appearing anywhere within the  labeled statement.

It goes on (emphasis added)

> If the statement is labeled by an Identifier and the contained Statement completes abruptly because of a break with the same Identifier, then **the labeled statement completes normally**. In all other cases of abrupt completion of the Statement, the labeled statement completes abruptly for the same reason.

So if you `break` an `if` block (remember a block is a statement), you can exit the `if` body. Let's test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (true) label: {
        if (args != null)
            break label;
        System.out.println("doesn't get here");
    }
    System.out.println("Outside of labeled block");
}
```

Output:

```
Outside of labeled block
```

Comment: note that there is no 'continue', i.e. with an if-else chain, the break will resume execution after the entire chain

Comment: Yes. I tried replacing `break` with `continue` there and got an error `Not a loop label`.

Answer (score 2):

The `break` statement breaks *loops* and does not transfer control to the label.

Using a label with `break` is for when you have inner and outer loops. An unlabeled `break` breaks the inner most loop (the one you are in) whereas a labeled `break` allows you to specify an outer loop.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Specifically the [BreakWithLabelDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/BreakWithLabelDemo.java)

Comment: The linked example demonstrates how `break` is used with loops, but it doesn't say that it has to be used with loops explicitly. I don't know why all answers seem to think that. You can use a `break` in an if statement, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use a recursive function.

```
public void work(){
    // some code
    if (x != 0 && y != 0) {
        //some code
    } else {
        work();
    }
}
```

You cannot use `break` without loops

Comment: `You cannot use break without loops` ~ Not entirely accurate. You can use break with a `switch` statement.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, labels cannot be used arbitrarily around `{}`, you need to do them to mark a for, while or do-while loop

Comment: you can label if-else statements as well: the compiler wouldn't raise errors. Of course, it would be no use since you can't "break" or "continue" them. :)